# Why is it not Shuffling the Second Array

Tags: java

I have got two JSON Arrays and i am combing them to get a Shuffle Array .

This is my program

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String weekArray = "[\"Sunday\", \"Monday\", \"Tuesday\", \"Wednesday\", \"Thursday\", \"Friday\", \"Saturday\"] ";
        String numberArray = "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\"] ";
        JSONArray allArray = new JSONArray(weekArray).put(numberArray);
        JSONArray shuffledArray = shuffleJsonArray(allArray);
        System.out.println(shuffledArray);
    }
    public static JSONArray shuffleJsonArray (JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = array.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
              int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
              // Simple swap
              Object object = array.get(j);
              array.put(j, array.get(i));
              array.put(i, object);
            }
        return array;
    }

}
```

When i run the above program the output is

```
["Saturday","Tuesday","Monday","Friday","[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\"] ","Thursday","Sunday","Wednesday"]
```

Please tell me why is it not shuffling the Second Array ?

Comment: Because the second array is not contained in the first array as an array, but as a single string element. That means the whole array is treated as one of the weekday strings.

Comment: ^ it's obvious once you look the the commas. The black comments in your code show you new elements. The numbers array is treated as 1 array element.

Comment: You don't need to implement Fisher-Yates shuffle yourself, it's already in the standard library: `java.util.Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array))`.

Answer (score 1):

The second array is inside the first array. Your shuffling algorithm only changes the order of the elements in the first array, so that the **position** of the second array inside the first array is changed. This does not influence the order of the elements **inside** the second array.

Furthermore, the second array actually is treated as a `String`, so you'd need to convert it to a `JSONArray` instance before running `shuffleJsonArray` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your **second array** *doesn't* assign as a **array** to the **first array** it's only assign as a one *String* to the first array .so your shuffle method(*shuffleJsonArray*) only change the index (position) of that one String (because to first array it's only a one String not a array)